# Codeigniter - Controller can't render view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I' facing a problem with trying to render login_view.php in my login.php controller. What I got is this error :

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Here is my controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //get form input
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email-ID','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FLASE)
        {
            //validation fail
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
        else
        {
            //check user credentials
            $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($email, $password);
            if(count($uresult)>0)
            {
                //set session
                $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->fname,'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                redirect('profile/index');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class = "alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email/Password</div>');
                redirect('login/index');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out whats the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check it on chrome ? What does Google Chrome say ?

Comment: @Nandan The localhost page isn’t working. Localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: is it "localhost/project_name/Login/index"  ??

Comment: I think there's something wrong with conditional logic in my controller, but i'm not sure where

Comment: yes, it's localhost/project_name/Login/index. anything wrong?

Comment: So you are not able to render  $this->load->view('login_view');
right? Try commenting that, and just echo something to check whether control is going to the same  if case.

Comment: It seems there is a typo in `if($this->form_validation->run() == FLASE)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load session library in autoload, since you will need it on other pages. Beside, you have a typo in the first if condition.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FLASE) // FIX FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you. Just noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! turns out I've mistaken using `redirect` instead of `$this->load->view('login_view');` and $`this->load->view('profile_view');`

It seems if I use `redirect` and the code will always check if the `if(count($uresult)>0)` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` and then continue with the action, The `redirect` action will always runs. So it's endless loop.

Check out the check user credentials conditional statement.